# Cannot scaffold DB: Microsoft.EntityFramework.Tools (invalid json file)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, scaffolding

I am using a .NET Core Console Application, I am trying to scaffold the database after I installed the required EF dependencies. Here is the project.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    }
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

When running this command in Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=PC;Database=DB;User Id=sa;Password=pass;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir EntityModels
```

It gives me the following:

> Unhandled Exception: System.MissingMethodException: Entry point not found in assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

Then, I installed last version of Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tool (version 3), Now when executing the scaffold command, it gives the following:

> Invalid JSON file in c:....\project.json

Comment: @stuartd Its not a duplicate anymore, but part of the problem is in another question. I am trying to add more clues to make it easier to investigate about this.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your only issue, but I have `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview3-final"`. Make sure all your nugets are latest. Also make sure you are on Visual Studio 2015 Update 3, latest tooling and latest core, etc. Also, at least powershell 3 (I'm using 4).

Comment: Based on your Request I added a new Console App, installed the latest nugets. Using Powershell 5, VS 2015 Update 3. Then, running the scaffold commad gives the following: **No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"**

Comment: Yeah, having the same problem with version 1.0.0-preview3-final

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when using 1.0.1. This isn't ideal, but until this is resolved in a future release, I use version `1.0.0-preview2-final` of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design` when running `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`, then revert back to 1.0.1 when the scaffold process is complete.

Be sure you do a package restore after each project.json change.

Here's my project.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",

    // use this version to build/run
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.0.1",

    // use this version when running `dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold`
    //"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
    //  "type": "build",
    //  "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
    //},

    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "System.Linq.Dynamic.Core": "1.0.6.5",
    "AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection": "1.1.2"
  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50",
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
          "type": "platform",
          "version": "1.0.1-*"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```